# SQL Server Express Casues CPU to Peg at 100% on Single Core Tablet

Tags: sql-server-express, cpu-usage

I am running an instance of SQL Server Express on an old underpowered tablet PC used for a special purpose application. Periodically the SQL Server process kicks in and hammers the CPU at 100% bringing the application to a halt. (Technically, it doesn't halt, it just slows it down to the point where key processes time-out.) It will be another two or three years before the hardware is replaced so that's not an option. Is there a way to throttle SQL Server Express?

Comment: have you determined what it is doing when it hits 100% CPU? Paging to disk? Lazy writer?

Comment: I don't know. How would I check?

Comment: What version of SQL Server Express are you using? Does the Event log give you any clue as to what's going on? I don't think you can throttle SQL Server Express, per se, but you might want to consider working around the problem. You could, for example, lengthen your timeouts or increase the priority of your application. There may still be an underlying problem, but maybe that's sufficient to get you through the next two or three years.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few techniques to identify CPU-hogging activity on MSSQL, but since your box is completely unresponsive at the time, you have few options.  Using SQL Profiler to run a background trace logging to a table or file might be your best bet.

Until very recently, you needed a paid version of MSSQL to use Profiler, however MS now includes Profiler with MSSQL Express 2012 SP1.  Here's a direct download link:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579

(Note, you can probably install Profiler without upgrading your MSSQL server instance, if you don't want to).

If you've never used Profiler to diagnose CPU-hogging queries before, here's how I would suggest going about it:

- new trace > connect to your MSSQL instace
- make sure the "CPU" column is selected
- make sure both the "started" and "completed" events for all the queries (Statement/Query/Batch/Procedure/etc) are checked.
- Use a "column filter" to only show events where there is a value in the "CPU" column
- Select a name for the trace, **and a destination** (table or .TRN file)
- Start the trace and leave it running

After experiencing the CPU issue, once your box recovers: open the trace results, paying particular attention to the CPU column, and the date/time the 100% utilization started.  Here's a link with more about using Profiler to analyze traces:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175848.aspx